# Tracking Facebook Shares and Comments on cascading users

Tags: facebook

Is there a way to track a post and as that post gets shared be able to view all the comments on all the cascaded shares? Or possible way to generate such a function?

Does the functionality change if I create a page for the post? Am I then able to see all the likes and comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try http://sociograph.io
It provides analytics for Facebook Pages and Facebook Groups.
You can search for any page or group and it will generate detailed report.
The report contains data about all posts, authors, commenters, likers and much more.
It's completely free.